# Phoenix 1.3 Using channel to insert data

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to update my application from phoenix 1.2 to 1.3.

In my Channel, one of `handle_in` functions get `order_id` and `food_id` to create `OrderItem`

```
changeset = order
|> build_assoc(:order_items)
|> Myapp.OrderItem.changeset(%{food_id: food.id,
                              price: food.price,
                              quantity: 1, 
                              order_id: order.id,
                              created_date: time_now})

case Repo.insert(changeset) do
  {:ok, order_item} ->
    max_rounds = Repo.one!(from p in Myapp.OrderItem, where: p.order_id == ^order.id, select: max(p.round))
    Myapp.Order.changeset(order, %{total: order.total + (order_item.price * order_item.quantity), rounds: max_rounds}) |> Repo.insert_or_update
end
```

So above code is from phoenix 1.2 version of app, what it does is that when a user successfully creates `order_item`, it updates `order`. It works fine.

```
with {:ok, %OrderItem{} = order_item} <- Myapp.create_order_item(%{food_id: food.id,
                                                                        price: food.price,                                                                                                                              
                                                                        order_id: order.id,
                                                                        created_date: time_now}) do    

 max_rounds = Repo.one!(from p in OrderItem, where: p.restaurant_order_id == ^order.id, select: max(p.round))
 Myapp.update_order(order, %{total: order.total + (order_item.price * order_item.quantity), rounds: max_rounds})
end
```

Phoenix 1.3 introduced new use of `model`, so I call `create_order_item` function from `Myapp` which has `Myapp.Order` and `Myapp.OrderItem` to create `order_item`.

```
def create_order_item(attrs \\ %{}) do
 %OrderItem{}
 |> order_item_changeset(attrs)
 |> Repo.insert()
end
```

Even though I pass all fields that I need to insert to database, it does not insert to database. How should I fix it? What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

---Edit

```
def create_order_item(attrs \\ %{}) do
 time_now = Ecto.DateTime.cast!
 (:calendar.universal_time_to_local_time(:calendar.universal_time()))
 %OrderItem{created_date: time_now}
 |> order_item_changeset(attrs)
 |> Repo.insert()
end
```

Comment: Do you get any error in the logs? or does the whole code run without errors but nothing is inserted?

Comment: It does not trigger any error and nothing is inserted.. If I remove `|> order_item_changeset(attrs)` in the `create_order_item` function, it inserts with only default field values..

Comment: What does `create_order_item` return? Try `IO.inspect(Myapp.create_order_item(...))`. It must be returning some error.

Comment: I see, it shows that it has error on `created_date`.`errors: [created_date: {"is invalid", [type: :utc_datetime, validation: :cast]}]`.. I use  `time_now = Ecto.DateTime.cast!(:calendar.universal_time_to_local_time(:calendar.universal_time()))`
to get current time to insert.. and in my schema, I have filed `field :created_date, :utc_datetime`.

Comment: Try removing `Ecto.DateTime.cast!` (just use the inner expression, i.e. `time_now = :calendar.universal_time_to_local_time(:calendar.universal_time)`).

Comment: I made it work by chainging `create_order_item` function like edit above.. Can I ask you that Why is it not possible to pass `created_date` to insert data?

Comment: Do you get the same error with the suggestion in my previous comment?

Comment: No, it works! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field has type `utc_datetime`, but you're passing a `Ecto.DateTime` to it, which cannot be casted into `utc_datetime`:

```
iex(1)> Ecto.Type.cast(:utc_datetime, Ecto.DateTime.utc())
:error
```

Instead, you can directly pass the Erlang datetime tuple returned by `:calendar.universal_time_to_local_time/1`:

```
time_now = :calendar.universal_time_to_local_time(:calendar.universal_time())
```

You can also instead just use `:calendar.local_time()` which does the same as above:

```
time_now = :calendar.local_time()
```

Also, you really should be handling the failure case when using `with`, otherwise the error case will be silently ignored, like it was being here, until we figured it out in the comments:

```
with {:ok, %OrderItem{} = order_item} <- Myapp.create_order_item(...) do    
 ...
else
  {:error, error} ->
    # handle error
end
```